# How to remove a resource using an Aspect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

[This change](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/17015) added support for Cloudwatch Logs Resource policies.

However in GovCloud, the `AWS::Logs::ResourcePolicy` is not part of the [cfn spec](https://s3.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/cfn-resource-specifications-us-gov-west-1-prod/latest/CloudFormationResourceSpecification.json).

I know you can use [Escape Hatches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_raw) to override properties, but can you also directly *remove* a resource?

I've started an Aspect

```py
@jsii.implements(IAspect)
class RemoveLogResourcePolicy:
    def visit(self, node: IConstruct):
        if (
            CfnResource.is_cfn_resource(node)
            and node.cfn_resource_type == "AWS::Logs::ResourcePolicy"
        ):
            # Can I somehow delete `node` here?
```

Perhaps I'm over complicating it?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running the following Aspect:

```py
@jsii.implements(IAspect)
class RemoveLogResourcePolicy:
    def visit(self, node: IConstruct):
        if isinstance(node, logs.ResourcePolicy):
            node.node.try_remove_child("ResourcePolicy")
```

I'm only applying this aspect if deploying to Govcloud

Comment: You can check the region from within the aspect, too.